# Requires Shared Library on Remote Computer

Tags: ubuntu, shared, privileges

I'm trying to run an executable on a remote computer, but I get the following error:

"error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

On my computer I can install libgmp or use ldconfig, but on the remove computer I do not have privileges to do so. I tried copying libgmp.so.3 from my computer to the remote directory where the executable that requires it is in, but I still get the same error.

Is there some way to tell the executable to look for shared libraries in the same folder it is in? Both are under Ubuntu 64 bit.

p.s. The system admin is away for some time, so I would like to get a solution which does not require having root privileges!

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: You can try setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the directory where you put the lib, see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/9878/set-ld-library-path-for-applications-started-from-the-desktop

Comment: This was the main issue. Thanks for the help!
p.s. Just notice I did not respond to your comment.